# Prepopulating form's textfields with bean default value in Struts2

Tags: struts2

In Struts 1.x , I have prepopulated the forms text fields using form bean's with default values as follows,

```
<html:form action="/actions/signup1">
First name: <html:text property="firstName"/><BR>
```

And in form bean, I have default value as follows...

```
public class ContactFormBean {
private String firstName = "First name";
```

But in Struts 2.x , when I tried with struts-tags textfield as follows, its not prepopulating the default value from the bean,

```
<s:form action="signup1">
    <s:textfield name="formBean.firstName" label = "First Name" />
```

I have the formBean declared in my Action class as follows with appropriate getter and setter methods...

```
public class SignupAction1 extends ActionSupport {
private ContactFormBean formBean;
@Override
    public String execute() throws Exception {
....
}
    public ContactFormBean getFormBean(){
        return formBean;
    }
    public void setFormBean(ContactFormBean fb){
        formBean = fb;
    }
}
```

Please let me know if this can be accomplished at Request level and not at session level.
Thanks in advance.

<--Edited-->

**struts.xml**

```
<struts>

    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />

    <package name="basicstruts2" extends="struts-default">

        <action name="index">
            <result>/index.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="signup">
            <result>/SignUp.jsp</result>
        </action>


    <action name="signup1" class="coreservlets.action.SignupAction1" method="execute">
    <result name="success">/SignUp-Confirmation.jsp</result>
    <result name="error">/SignUp.jsp</result>

  </action>



    </package>

</struts>
```

**SignUp.jsp**

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Sign UP</title>
</head>
<body>
<H1 ALIGN="CENTER">Sign Up</H1>
<s:form>
    <s:textfield name="formBean.firstName" label = "First Name" />
    <s:textfield name="formBean.lastName" label = "Last Name" />
    <s:textfield name="formBean.email" label = "Email Address" />
    <s:textfield name="formBean.faxNumber" label = "Fax Number" />
    <s:submit action="signup1" method="loginAfterSubmit" value="Click here to Submit"/>
</s:form>
</body>
</html>
```

**ContactFormBean.java**

```
public class ContactFormBean {
    private String firstName = "First name";
    private String lastName = "Last name";
    private String email = "user@host";
    private String faxNumber = "xxx-yyy-zzzz";


    public String getFirstName() {
    return this.firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
    return(lastName);
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
    return(email);
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
    }
    public String getFaxNumber() {
    return(faxNumber);
    }
    public void setFaxNumber(String faxNumber) {
    this.faxNumber = faxNumber;
    }
public boolean isMissing(String value) {
        if ((value == null) || (value.trim().equals(""))) {
        return(true);
        } else {
        for(int i=0; i<defaultValues.length; i++) {
        if (value.equals(defaultValues[i])) {
        return(true);
        }
        }
        return(false);
        }
        }

}
```

**SignupAction1.java**

```
public class SignupAction1 extends ActionSupport {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private ContactFormBean formBean;

    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception {
        this.formBean = new ContactFormBean();
        return SUCCESS;

    }

    public String loginAfterSubmit() {

        String firstName = formBean.getFirstName();
        String lastName = formBean.getLastName();
        String email = formBean.getEmail();
        String faxNumber = formBean.getFaxNumber();
        if (formBean.isMissing(firstName)) {
        return ERROR;
        } else if (formBean.isMissing(lastName)) {
        return ERROR;
        } else if ((formBean.isMissing(email)) ||
        (email.indexOf("@") == -1)) {
        return ERROR;
        } else if (formBean.isMissing(faxNumber)) {
        return ERROR;
        } else {
        return SUCCESS;
        }
    }


    public ContactFormBean getFormBean(){
                return this.formBean;
    }
    public void setFormBean(ContactFormBean fb){
        formBean = fb;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `signup` action declaration to

```
<action name="signup" class="coreservlets.action.SignupAction1">
   <result>/SignUp.jsp</result>
</action>
```

and `signup1` to

```
<action name="signup1" class="coreservlets.action.SignupAction1" method="signup1">
```

create method `signup1` in your `SignupAction1` action class and move your logic from `execute` to it. In `execute` then create new instance of your `ContactFormBean`.

Comment: thank u ! it worked. I was not having Action class conffigured for signup jsp in struts.xml before and thats the problem.

Comment: @AleksandrM: I'm pretty sure `name` is enough for textfield, `value` is not needed unless you wanna show something different from the straight value out from the getter :)

Comment: @AndreaLigios: Yes, you are right. Going to delete this from my answer.

Answer (score 0):

put your default value to the constructor:

```
public class ContactFormBean {
    private String firstname;
    public ContactFormBean (){
        this.firstName = "First name";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a null `formBean` object with the `getFormBean` method,
then the constructor is never called and the attempt to acces the formBean attribute `firstName` is giving an error (that is not showed because it is wrapped by the Struts2 tag on the JSP.

You can

1) instantiate it on your execute method:

```
public String execute() throws Exception {
   this.formBean = new ContactFormBean();
}
```

2) instantiate it lazily on your getter:

```
public ContactFormBean getFormBean(){
    if (formBean==null) 
       this.formBean = new ContactFormBean();
    return this.formBean;
}
```

---

EDIT (due to your comments):

I don't know how you've structured your web application;

But if you are on a JSP, an Action (and its execute() method, or another method if specified) was called BEFORE rendering the JSP.

So, regardless if you have ActionOne loading stuff and ActionTwo called after submit, or ActionOne loading stuff and another method of ActionOne called after submit, you can know if you are in a "pre-JSP" state or in a "post-submit" state...

That said, if you are exposing an Object, and you want its value or its attributes to be different from `null`, you have to instantiate it in one of the way described above.

Obviously, your object should contain getters and setters for its attributes, and they must have been bound to your JSP objects.

In your example, you could have:

ContactFormBean:

```
public class ContactFormBean {
   private String firstName = "First name";
   public String getFirstName(){
      return this.firstName;
   }
   public String setFirstName(String firstName){
      this.firstName = firstName;
   }
}
```

Your Action:

```
public class SignupAction1 extends ActionSupport {
    private ContactFormBean formBean;

    public ContactFormBean getFormBean(){
        return formBean;
    }
    public void setFormBean(ContactFormBean fb){
        formBean = fb;
    }


    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception {
       /* this method is executed before showing the JSP */

       /* first time initialization */
       this.formBean = new ContactFormBean();
       return SUCCESS;
    }

    public String loginAfterSubmit() throws Exception {
       /* this method is executed after the submit button was pressed */

       /* i don't initialize nothing here, 
          ContactFormBean is coming from the page */ 

       System.out.println("ContactFormBean's firstName value is: " +
                          this.formBean.getFirstName());
       return "goSomewhereElse";
    }

}
```

and in Your JSP:

```
<s:form>
   <s:textfield name="formBean.firstName" label = "First Name" />
   <s:submit action="signup1" method="loginAfterSubmit" value="Press here to submit" />
</s:form>
```

You can do this with two Action by splitting the execute() and the loginAfterSubmit() methods into two execute() methods of two different Actions;

Then you must have your formBean in BOTH the Actions, with at least the getter in the first, and the setter in the second.

Comment: well, instantiating formBean on execute method is overiding my form entered values into bean fields !! That is, each time submit button is clicked and control goes to execute method of Action class, and when I do, String firstName = formBean.getFirstName(); its picking default values and not the form entered values. So I should not have business logic inside execute method?

Comment: Also I think formBean will get instantiated only after Action class is called. So there is no way it can get values when jsp form is rendered on first time. I mean only after submit button is pressed and control goes to Action class, bean gets instantiated and after returning either success or failure and mapping to this jsp accordingly in struts.xml , does this textfields are getting populated from bean. So my question to populate the jsp form on initial rendering itself. Hope you are clear.

Comment: Followed what you said but still not success. Let me paste the entire code including struts.xml in the above under the comments <--Edited--> Please check if I did your way.

Answer (score 0):

You can also set the Name value in your bean in execute method, it will populate it in your JSP page. Example is :

```
public String execute() throws Exception {
    this.formBean = new ContactFormBean();
    //Set your Name value here        
    formBean.setName("John Doe");
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

Once JSP is populated you will find this value in Name text box.
Hope this will help.

Tapan